# Dynamic SQL to store the execution result in a variable and concatenate that result to form a full query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I was trying to make a query with dynamic column name.So that the final query can execute

```
DECLARE @SQLFinal NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLAlias NVARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT '',''+cast(ColumnName as varchar(20)) + '' as '' + cast(ColAliasName as varchar(20)) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS from #colandAlias' 
DECLARE @SQLAliasResult NVARCHAR(MAX)
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLAlias= @SQLAliasResult OUTPUT
select  @SQLAliasResult
```

--Assigned the sp_execute result to a variable , @SQLAliasResult.It gives NULL instead of the exec result

-- the intention is to concatinate the above result(@SQLAliasResult) with belwo query part to form a full query

```
set @SQLFinal='SELECT

ID,Name,custid '

+@SQLAliasResult+
' FROM dbo.tableCustomer where custid=71'

EXEC @SQLFinal
```

-- how to assign the query execution result in a variable and execute @SQLFinal ?

---output of the@SQLAliasResult

```
,col1 as [201911]
,col2 as [201912]
,col1 as [202001]
,col2 as [202002]
```

--The content of @SQLFinal

```
SELECT
ID,Name,custid 
,col1 as [201911]
,col2 as [201912]
,col1 as [202001]
,col2 as [202002]
FROM dbo.tableCustomer where custid=71
```

exec @SQLFinal would give the required out put from the dbo.tableCustomer with generated aliases

Comment: Is the OUTPUT a table? I believe you want the `INSERT...EXEC` pattern here.

Comment: From what you posted there is no need for dynamic sql in the first place. This appears to be an overly complicated way of doing whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense, which makes the question not very clear. What is it that you're trying to do in the first place? [(proper)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) Sample data and expected output would make this question much better.

Comment: add the sample output for SQLAliasResult and the final output  SQLFinal

Comment: @user1254579 there's nothing dynamic there - what are you trying to do? This query even repeats the same columns/values under different aliases. If you wanted to create a snapshot query with a customer's totals over the last 4 months, there are better ways.

Comment: You have a temp table inside `@SQLAlias`, which could be the problem. Why don't you just PRINT `@SQLFinal` and run the query from there?

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there's no need for dynamic query in line 2, I see no dynamic fields. Also, I think that you need something like this:

```
DECLARE @Columns TABLE(
    ColumnName SYSNAME
)

INSERT INTO @Columns VALUES ( 'Column1' ), ( 'Column2' );

DECLARE @SelectString   VARCHAR(255)

-- This is the sentence that is going to concat everything
SELECT  @SelectString = ISNULL( @SelectString + ', ', '' ) + ColumnName
    FROM @Columns;

-- Execute this or do what you need
SELECT @SelectString;
```